# I had a (password protected) postgres docker container running on a public port for a few minutes

Tags: docker, postgresql

Could the server be compromised? I've deleted the container.

Comment: Probably not. I'm not familiar with Docker but I'd imagine you have some logs you can look at in the host system to make some determination of compromise.

Comment: good job deleting the container before you had a chance to look inside...

Comment: "Could it be compromised?" Yes. But that could be the answer no matter what the details of the question are.

Comment: Unless you're running an old exploitable kernel/docker version (or the attacker spent a zero-day on you), then the container only had access to the resources that you gave it. Unless you mounted your whole filesystem or parts storing important configs or executables into the container, then even if an attacker compromised the container, they wouldn't be able to compromise the rest of the server.